# Select some of rows in C# database connection

Tags: c#, sql, database

I used database connection for connect to database and I selected some of rows in database table, like this code:

```
OleDbConnection objConnection = new OleDbConnection("server=localhost;database=sample;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\sample.accdb");

objDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT description, category, account, price FROM SampleTable WHERE Select_ID = 12", objConnection);
```

now this code select 16 rows from SampleTable where Select_ID is 12 after that i need rows 3,5,7 how can i select this rows?

Comment: Why do you want to select the rows 3,5,7 ? What is special about them ? Tell us the criteria on which you are selecting those records ?

Comment: when is selected SampleTable rows where Select_ID is 12 so it will choose  16 records from table, but i need row 3,5,7 from this selection

Comment: My question: Do you need row 3, 5 and 7 also for other 'Select_ID' then 12?

Comment: Rows 3,5,7 according to which ordering? A table has no implicit order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // get your data into this datatable

        DataRow[] dr;
        dr = dt.Select("WHERE Select_ID = 12");
        if (dr.Length > 0)
        {
            //do something
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't do what OP wants even if you would change it to `dr = dt.Select("Select_ID = 12");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186734.aspx) function. If you use it in the query you have, you will select by ROW_NUMBER of ALL rows. If I read correctly, you want rows 3,5,7 of the result set, so you would have to use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT description, category, account, price FROM SampleTable WHERE Select_ID = 12
) WHERE ROW_NUMBER() IN (3,5,7)
```

In the inner query, you are getting the 16-row result. The outer query now uses that result as a table/data source and selects the rows you need.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() may be used "SELECT" or "ORDER BY", I corrected you answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29385311/4268592)

Answer (score 0):

if order by column "id", then

```
SELECT t.description, t.category, t.account, t.price FROM (
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as RowN, description, category, account, price FROM SampleTable WHERE Select_ID = 12
) as t WHERE RowN in (3,5,7)
```

else (ORDER BY id) change to your column

Answer (score 0):

If your `DataTable` already contains those 16 rows but you want only row 3,5,7:

```
int[] indexes = { 2, 4, 6 };
dataTable1 = dataTable1.AsEnumerable()
    .Where((row, index) => indexes.Contains(index))
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

If you use a database that supports ranking functions you could use `ROW_NUMBER`. If you use SQL-Server >=2005 this works:

```
string sql = @"
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT description, category, account, price,
           rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Select_ID, description, category, account, price)
    FROM SampleTable 
    WHERE Select_ID = 12
)
SELECT description, category, account, price
FROM CTE
WHERE rn IN ( 3, 5, 7 );"
```